# Bind TextArea linebreaks to html

Tags: ember.js

I have a textarea binded to a div such that anything you type in the textarea updates the div.

The only thing that bindings doesn't respect is newlines in textarea so if you hit 'enter' within textarea, the div doesn't get a break.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/Ajkyw/19/

I am using a helper and it doesn't work.

As per Point 4 on this link: http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/, it is not supposed to work. But even with the solution on that link, I can't get it to work.

Any ideas on how to update the div with `<br/>` tags on linebreaks within the textarea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a computed property to format the location's line breaks.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#with App.obj}}
        {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="location"}}  
        <div>{{{formattedLocation}}}</div>
    {{/with}}
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
App.obj = Ember.Object.create({
    location:'Palo Alto',

    formattedLocation: function() {
        return this.get('location').replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');
    }.property('location').cacheable()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8G2j/

In the example I removed your helper so it would be a bit easier to follow exactly what is going on. If you need to use a helper and are unable to figure it out let me know and I will add the helper back in.

Comment: I tried this approach as well but my br tags were getting escaped. I noticed you are wrapping with 3 parens aka {{{location}}} instead of 2 which is normal. Any reference/documentation link to the 3 parens?

Comment: Got it. Handlebars documentation tells about the triple mustache trick: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I don't think it's very safe to use the "triple-stash" {{{}}}, as the content might contain HTML/JS, opening your site to vulnerabilities. I'd recommend using a helper like so: https://gist.github.com/lagartoflojo/6090175. This snippet first escapes the contents and then replaces \n\r's with <br>'s.

Comment: @Hernan thanks for the tip, code from github works like a charm.